# Statistical Spell Checking: General Approach and Avoid Feedback Loops

Tags: algorithm, nlp, spell-checking

A database I am building has a large number of names, that are often repeated. However, many names have misspellings, and I want to attempt to automatically correct the misspellings. I do not know the correct list of names before-hand.

My current approach has been to keep a list of the top `N` names along with their frequencies in the corpus. Then, when a new name is input into the database, I find the name which maximizes `term_freq(name) / edit_distance(new_name, name)`. That is, I find an existing name in the top `N` names that with the highest frequency divided by the edit distance between the candidate name and the candidate.

Is this a sound approach to checking for names?  Am I going about this incorrectly?

I am concerned that if the system detects a group of documents that misspell a name, they can make it into the top `N` names, and then cause all other names to change as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all... I'm obligated to say that I suspect you'll create more trouble with this than you save, and that you might be happier just requiring everyone to spell things correctly (and accept that things will break in a nice, predictable way if they don't). That being said, if you're going to do things this way, I would look to Baye's law:

`P(H|E) = P(H) * P(E|H) / P(E)`

(That reads: "The probability of a hypothesis given certain evidence is equal to the probability of the hypothesis multiplied by the probability of the evidence given the hypothesis, divided by the probability of the evidence.")

In this case, you would be considering the probability that a name is a mis-spelled version of another name, given the frequencies and some pre-conceived expectations about the likelyhood of typos:

- `P(H)` would be the probability of (some number of specific typos | length of name)
- `P(E)` would be the base probability of seeing this name (for this, I would keep the un-modified list of all entered words)
- `P(E|H)` would be the sum of probabilities of all names that are (some number of typos) away from this name.

I would then compare the results of that to the probability that they were right in the first place, i.e., `P(Zero Typos| Length of Name) * P(This Spelling)`.

Comment: I understand Baye's, the issue is implementing it on a larger scale (this database is Terabytes, and is constantly expanding). To keep track of `P(H)` and `P(E)`, I'll need to store the incorrectly spelled names in my database, right? Then, if I want users to query for the corrected ones, I'll need a separate copy, right?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to avoid having to store the incorrectly spelled names, without introducing serious problems (especially if new names start to appear.) For instance, suppose "Dan" makes it into the top `N` names early on, but "Don" doesn't. Even if "Don" turns out to be *more* common in the long run, you'll have no way to learn that, if you aren't storing "incorrect" things. I'm not sure what you mean by "Query for the corrected ones."